# watir-webdriver click_no_wait

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script that hangs after I click a link.  This link launches a popup where the user then selects some options and the clicks the submit button to generate a report.  After I click on the link the script it will hang indefinitely until I kill it.  I am running my tests on a mac osx using chromedriver.  I have tried firefox and safari and get same result. there is no click_no_wait in the elements.rb. It seems to only be for windows and ie.  I have the latest install, so Is there a way to make the script execute the link and then not wait so that I can access the popup and process the form contained with in it?

Here is the link I need to click on:

```
b.frame(:name, "ifContentBody").link(:text, "Filter").click
```

javascript:

```
openMdlWindow('InvestmentDetailOptions.aspx?IDAssetType=', '620', '600');
if (window.document.RetValue == '2') {
    window.parent.LoadinIframe('InvestmentDetail.aspx?FromMenu=N&amp;IDAssetType=', 'Investment Details &gt; Full View', 'false');
}
```

I have searched a million+ posts and sites and can not find the solution.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see these?

http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/
http://watirwebdriver.com/browser-popups/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.  Yes I have seen these and every other suggested out there. The issue I believe is the javascript link does not stop loading or running so I cannot move past it.  It freezes the script and then times out.  What I am looking for is a way to tell it not to wait and go on to next command.  This popup contains a form that I need to select dates and radio buttons then submit. That will then generate the data I need to download.   I have tried it in applescript/safari and in applescript there is an "ignore application response" that will let me move on to next line.